# Pass AD username into view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I am able to get users' information from AD by using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.

I am also able to get username without domain as shown below. My question is how can i pass this information to my view?

```
 DirectoryContextMock directorycontent = new DirectoryContextMock();

 System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
 System.Security.Principal.IIdentity identity = user.Identity;
 string a= identity.Name.Substring(identity.Name.IndexOf(@"\") + 1);
```

Currently i have the following code in my view and it works but i want to pass "a" into this view instead of @User.Identity.Name. It seems like very easy thing to do but i couldnt able to do so.

```
Hello, <span class="username">@User.Identity.Name</span>!
```

Comment: Where are you actually defining `a`?  You view can access it if it's part of the model, part of some view data (`ViewBag`, `TempData`, etc.), a static property somewhere, etc.

Comment: I am defining it in my controller.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Views in MVC are derived from [WebViewPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg402107(v=vs.118).aspx) that already contain a property  [`IPrincipal User`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagerenderingbase.user(v=vs.118).aspx).  So why duplicate what is already available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comments above you say that `a` is being defined in your controller.  So you have a couple of very simple options for sending that data to your view:

1) Make a property on your model and store the value of `a` on that property.

2) Add it to the `ViewBag`, for example:

```
// in the controller action
ViewBag.Username = a;

// in the view
@ViewBag.Username
```

You can use other temporary storage mechanisms analogous to `ViewBag` as well, such as `TempData` or `ViewData`.  (`ViewData` and `ViewBag` serve very similar purposes, the latter was added to the framework in later versions.)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a property to your model that you are passing into the view.

If you're not using a model, you can use the `ViewBag` dynamic property.

```
   public class MyModel
    {
       public string Identity {get;set;}
    }

    public class MyController : BaseController
    {

        public ActionResult Get()
        {
           var myModel = new MyModel();
           myModel.Identity = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

           //snip
           return View(myModel);
        }
    }
```